# Can't set default app?

Tags: applications, settings, default-applications

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge, and I was trying to open a Tumblr link from Facebook messenger. When the popup to choose a default app showed up, I accidentally chose Chrome.

I tried resetting the default settings on Chrome, but when the popup to choose a default app shows up again, Tumblr is no longer on the list. It just lists Chrome and another browser that I have.

I tried everything I could think of. I've reinstalled both Chrome and Tumblr, I cleaned out caches, and I've restarted my phone. I also tried to manually set Tumblr as default but selecting "via this app" on the "go to supported URLs" setting. When I disabled Chrome and uninstalled other browsers, a "can't open link popup shows up when I try to open a Tumblr link. This is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings > Apps in your phone. Find Chrome. You will find an "Open by Default" option for anything you have asked it to open earlier. Clear it.